# Bootstrap 5 Table toolbar jumping while loading page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, toolbar

I am using Bootstrap 5 to display a table with  toolbar class e.g data-search , the problem is, that the page is "jumping" during the loading process.

Here is the code for the table:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-toolbar=".toolbar" data-sort-class="table-active" data-search="true" data-sortable="true" data-sort-name="id" data-sort-order="asc" class="table">
```

With the above code the search field "jumps" down e.g. moves the page down, when the toolbar is geting active.

Does anyone know the css trick to fix the height of the toolbar class, that the page does not "jump" anymore while loading?

Comment: Seems like you're talking about the [Bootstrap Table Toolbar here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/toolbar/). Am I right? This is more than just Bootstrap 5. Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. For instance by using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). I tried the example in the first link, and there's no real jump for me when it comes to the toolbar.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hi, I will add some code in a moment. Thx so far.